# Passing 'this' to Axios promise 'then'?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I have a redux-form with password field, trying to update the password word field with random number in this simple example. How to bind the 'this' to Axios catch function?

```
axios.get('https://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=20&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new').then(function(result) {
  this.props.change('password', result.data);
})
.then(function(response) {
//
})
.catch(function(error) {
  this.props.change('password', '999');
});
```

I know the above logic works fine because if I use an ES5 var this1 = this; and use this1 it works fine.

Regards!

Answer (score 3):

Either you can use the method you've just described, i.e.

```
var $this = this
var func = function() {
  $this.props.doSomething()
}
```

Or then you can `bind` the function to be executed with the right `this` context. In vanilla JS you can do it by using [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
var func = function() {
  this.props.doSomething()
}
// now this inside func will always be whatever it was here
func = func.bind(this)
```

In es6 binding `this` to anonymous functions has been simplified with [arrow functions](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html):

```
const func = () => {
  // this will be always whatever it was where this func was defined
  this.props.doSomething()
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I made a change and using ES6 fat arrow function, but it is not getting access to 'this'. I even tried passing it. [Note: using promise.all now]
const func = () => {Promise.all([axios.get('https://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=20&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new')])
  .then(function(result) {
     console.log('promise fullfilled result.data =', result);
     this.props.change('password', result[0].data);
    })
     .catch(function(error) {
     console.log('promise error =', error);
      this.props.change('password','999');
});
};
func(this);

Comment: then for some reason the function where you're invoking axios does not have the correct `this` context. Using the fat arrow function is just a fancy way of doing `var $this = this`.

Comment: Thank you so much.